# MyISAM racing conditions / LOCK TABLES

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, myisam

My 'invoices' table:

```
CREATE TABLE `invoices` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `invoice_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`invoice_id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `invoice_id` (`invoice_id`),
 KEY `order_id` (`order_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=115 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

When I try the query :

```
mysqli_query($conn, "LOCK TABLES 'invoices' WRITE");
```

in a php script, it doesn't work as I can insert a new row in the "locked" table using phpMyAdmin's SQL console during lock time.

May I be totally confident that a query like this

```
INSERT INTO `invoices` (`invoice_id`) SELECT MAX(`invoice_id`)+100 FROM `invoices`
```

can successfully prevents race conditions so to use this instead of a LOCK TABLES query;

NOTES:

- I did not create this table.
- I may not alter the table.

Comment: `'invoices'` should be wrapped with back ticks but not single quotes: `\`invoices\``

Comment: Your `invoice_id` column is already auto_increment so rely on it to do its job. Don't mess around trying to create other values from it.

Comment: @Dave Oh no, It's not. Anyway, I tested your assumption and it did not work. Also, I want the new entry for an invoice_id value to be max + 100, not  +1.

Comment: @Alex You are absolutely right. invoices should be wrapped with back ticks or  should be not wrapped at all. LOCK works!! Would you mind to write an answer that I can accept? I would also appreciate any comment you may have about INSERT...SELECT query.

Comment: There are _many_ ways where `AUTO_INCREMENT` can skip numbers -- do you really want to depend on it for numbering your Invoices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write an sql query you should be wrap table|column names  with back ticks but not single quotes.

In your case

```
 mysqli_query($conn, "LOCK TABLES `invoices` WRITE");
```

**Note** But I would recommend you to stop trying to "resolve" racing condition. Why did you decide that it is a problem in your case?

Racing condition could be a big problem for some projects. But I doubt that it is your case. I would support @Dave comment, you already have auto incremented index. That is more than enough in many cases.

Imho you don't need this "locks".

```
INSERT INTO `invoices` (`invoice_id`) SELECT MAX(`invoice_id`)+100 FROM `invoices`
```

This query has almost no sense. Could you explain why are you trying to do this weird insert?

Comment: I thought that **if** this SELECT runs when the table is locked by this INSERT for a client session then I can be sure that other client sessions can not change the table during that time. What is mentioned at MySQL 5.7 manual `When selecting from and inserting into the same table, MySQL creates an internal temporary table to hold the rows from the SELECT and then inserts those rows into the target table.`

Comment: @Gfour **WHY** do you need to `INSERT` from `SELECT`?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the lock only lasts for the duration of your database session - in this case the duration of your script call.

Comment: @vodka Yes, so I've set sleep(60) between LOCK - UNLOCK getting enough time for test.